# Use of Environment Variables to specify data connection strings in web.config

Tags: asp.net, environment-variables, connection-string, appsettings

I have been applying separate web.config files for each environoment as my ASP.NET application progresses through Development, IT, UA and Production and have been looking for a way to simplify this process.
In the past, these had been updated manually; this was tiresome and prone to human error. More recently, I've been using IBM's uDeploy to push the application with an environment-specific config file deployed with the application depending on the target environment.

I've seen many suggestions, such as separate config files (as per my current setup), use of pre-build events etc. However, I implemented a solution to this issue in our test environment whereby I assigned the database connection strings to environment variables on my application server. The relevant environment variable is then passed into my data access connection method. 
In other words, each environment's application server has an environment variable with the same name but with a different value assigned. This solution is quite simple and easily implemented and appears to function correctly.

Does anyone else manage separate environment configurations in this way? Are there any disadvantages to this approach that I have failed to consider?